# Element.getBoundingClientRect() on dom with applied CSS3 perspective Property return DOMRect object as before transformation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know if it is possible to return coordinates for a div being transformed using CSS3 perspective property using `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

I notice that `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` works fine for CSS 3 Transforms like `scale()` `skewX()`, but when `perspective` is applied, values returned ([DOMRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMClientRect)) do not match the dom element size after the transformation.

In my case I need to make sure that div with id `bb` has the width/height/top/left position on top of the bounding box for the element after the CSS transformation (as you see now the blue box match the element before transformation).

Any idea is welcome.

```js
var elm = document.querySelector('#div2');
var elmBb = document.querySelector('#bb');
var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
//console.log(rect);
elmBb.style.top = rect.top + 'px';
elmBb.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
elmBb.style.width = rect.width + 'px';
elmBb.style.height = rect.height + 'px';
```

```css
#div1 {
  position: fixed;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  perspective: 150px;
}

#div2 {
  padding: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
}

#bb {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">HELLO</div>
</div>
<div id="bb"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this issue, in order to return bounding box on the element which has a transformation and perspective applies it is necessary to use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` on the dom for the element transformed and not on its parent container where the `perspective` is applied as in the following example.

```js
var elm = document.querySelector('#div2');
var elmBb = document.querySelector('#bb');
var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(rect);
elmBb.style.top = rect.top + 'px';
elmBb.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
elmBb.style.width = rect.width + 'px';
elmBb.style.height = rect.height + 'px';
```

```css
#div1 {
  position: fixed;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  perspective: 150px;
}

#div2 {
  padding: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
}

#bb {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">HELLO</div>
</div>
<div id="bb"></div>
```